# Lag in UICollectionView Initial Scroll for Cells with Images

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a vertically scrolling `uicollectionview` that loads cells with a subclassed `uiimageview` that downloads an image via a url string.

My network call is in the background thread and moreover, I am utilizing the cache, but I do not understand why there is still an initial lag when I scroll. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ACollectionViewCell
        cell.populate(with: url)
        return cell
    }
}

class ACollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: PictureImageView!
    
    func populate(with url: String) {
        imageView.loadImageUsingUrlString(urlString: url)
    }
}

let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()

class PictureImageView: UIImageView {
    var imageUrlString: String?
    
    func loadImageUsingUrlString(urlString: String) {
        imageUrlString = urlString
        
        image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "blank_oval")
        contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        layer.cornerRadius = frame.width/2
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "blank_oval")
            return
        }
        
        if let imageFromCache = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as NSString) {
            print("Fetched image from cache")
            image = imageFromCache
            return
        }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("Failed to fetch profile image:", error)
            self.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "blank_oval")
            return
        }
            
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let data = data, let imageToCache = UIImage(data: data) else {
                self.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "blank_oval")
                return
            }
            if self.imageUrlString == urlString {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.image = imageToCache
                }
                
            }
            imageCache.setObject(imageToCache, forKey: urlString as NSString)
        }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the last 5 years pretty much every project I've worked on uses this. It's a bullet proof implementation for images required from a remote service.

[SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage)

Comment: appreciate the library. was curious if you had any thoughts/solves on my problem relative to the code i had posted? am hoping to solve without needed to add another framework.